# After refresh the text box is not becoming null

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

After refresh the text box is not becoming null.Instead it is holding the value which is entered.I am doing pagination

```
<form method='post' class="search" action="<?= base_url() ?>my-subscriptions">
     <input type='text' class="productsearch " name='search' value='<?= $search ?>' style="margin-left:-47px;    width: 226px !important; height: 40px; border-radius: 7px;border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;padding-left: 10px;outline: none;font-size:12px !important;">
     <input type='submit' name='submit' value="search" class="btn btn-info" role="button" style="background-color: #FF6347;border-color: #FF6347;border-radius: 20px;width: 81px !important;height: 33px !important;font-size:15px !important;">
   </form>
```

[image: this is my textbox it is getting clear when I manually clear thetext by using backspace I want it to be cleared on refresh]

this is my textbox it is getting clear when I manually clear the text by using backspace and by clicking on search it works fine I want it to be cleared on refresh and should go back to the main page

Comment: Have you tried the `autocomplete="off"` attribute?

Comment: try `autocomplete="off"` in that text box as attribute

Comment: @user7290573 Yes i tried that it is also not working is there anyother solution from which you can help

Comment: @M.Hemant I tried that not working

Comment: Can you post the PHP code here? Are you storing that text-box value into `$search` variable?

Comment: Try autocomplete attr in `form` tag too.. Is that in any specific browser?

Comment: @TamilvananN No still its not working

Comment: Can you post controller code from where $search is coming?

Answer (score 0):

This code will clear the input box when you refresh the page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input[type=text]').val('');
</script>
```

I hope it solves the issue.

Comment: That's going to clear *every* `input`, though. You should use a more specific selector such as `.productsearch`.